# How to fix "cannot find the file" when trying to connect to Internet Radio in WMP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, internet-radio

I've recently run into a problem with WMP 12 being able to stream from Internet radio stations via the Windows Media Guide. I have all the protocols turned on, temporarily turned off Windows Firewall, and have autodetect set in IE Network Connections.

I can get to the Windows Media Guide and can click on the **Listen** button for a station. Whenever I do this, I get a dialog box that says *Windows Media Player cannot find the file. If you are trying to play, burn, or sync an item that is in your library, the item might point to a file that has been moved, renamed, or deleted.*

Does anyone know why this occurs and what to do about it? I can play local music and other media via WMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Since WMP uses IE security settings, open IE, Under Tools, then Internet Options >Security Tab, reset "Internet" security settings back to default using the "default level" button.

You can also reach Internet options via control panel.

If that does not work there is an IE reset button on the advanced tab, try that.

Comment: I tried that just now and no dice. I also tried killing any/all IE instances after setting to Medium trust with Protected Mode off, and still no change :(

Comment: The **Advanced-->Reset...** did the trick! Thank you!